# If statement stops working after 9 items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Within woo commerce I am pulling all of the featured items into the home page. Within the featured Items I have an if statement nested so that it checks to see what category each featured item is in.

I am doing so so that if its in the category flower I can ad the suffix OZ to the price and within concentrates I can add the suffix GM to the price.

It works great with 9 items or less. Once more than 9 items are applied they are all displaying OZ no matter what the category.

There are a few other things in there checking for logged in vs not logged in.  but here is the whole snippet

```
<!------ check cat -->

        <?php
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
?>
<?php if ( in_array( 'flower', $categories ) ) { ?>

        <div class="price_home">
<div class="product__inside__price price-box">
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo wp_kses_post($price_html); ?> oz</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php } elseif ( in_array( 'concentrates', $categories ) ) { ?>

        <div class="price_home">
<div class="product__inside__price price-box">
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo wp_kses_post($price_html); ?> gm</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>

        <div class="price_home">
<div class="product__inside__price price-box">
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo wp_kses_post($price_html); ? 
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>

<? } ?>
```

I simplified this code but as I stated in the comments. This is used to split out the featured products. So I'm not 100% sure this is the issue, but people were having an issue viewing so much code.

Comment: What if statements are you talking about? Can you minimize the code to what is necessary?

Comment: The if statement that splits the code out by cat is here. But i'm not 100% sure thats the issue so thats the whole code for pulling in the featured products as well.

Comment: <?php } elseif ( in_array( 'concentrates', $categories ) ) { ?>
 is the start of the if for the split yes.

Comment: Simplify the code (see [how to create a minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  There's a lot to wade through.  And _for your own sake_ (as well as ours), learn to **indent and format** your php.  It's very difficult to track what is / is not nested inside of for loops and if statements in that code block.

Comment: You may want to do some dumping/logging if `$price_html = $product->get_price_html()` turns out to be true to find out exactly what it does contain when you hit the ones you think shouldn't apply it.

Comment: you are all focusing on the wrong part of the if statement, that is standard woocommerce code to pull in the pricing. That has nothing to do with the issue. The if statement is parsing though the featured products. Then looking though them for specific categories. 

$price_html etc will always be true, there will always be a price.

Comment: Ah, so it's because `flowers` is always in the array? You don't show where `$categories` is initially defined, or if that whole section is within a loop, but you may want to reset `$categories` with `$categories = [];` right before you build it up with the `$term->slug` foreach.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!